# Como não retornar um valor None no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código de exemplo:

```
lista = [100,200,1000,3000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def regras(x):
    if x < 100:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x
    if x >= 100:
        return (x+x)


v1 = list(map(regras,lista))
print(v1)
```

que tem essa saída

> [200, 400, 2000, 6000, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8]

Como posso ignorar esse `None`? Eu até coloquei um `else` com `return 0` mas quero que ele apenas ignore e fique assim:

> [200, 400, 2000, 6000, 2, 4, 6, 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa aprender usar o `else` que é a contraparte do `if`, ou seja, sempre que o `if` der falso ele cai no bloco do `else`, se existir um, no seu caso não existe, o erro ocorre porque em determinada condição você retorna um valor, e se ela for falsa você não retorna já que nada será executado, não faz sentido, então todos os caminhos possíveis precisam retornar algo. E ele pode ser usado para resolver o problema apresentado e pode usar outro para evitar 2 `if`s já que um é exatamente o oposto do outro, no fundo ele é um `else`.

Mas o que você quer mesmo é filtrar a lista (pegar só os resultados que interessam e não fazer uma operação em todos os dados, que é o que o `map()` faz) e não mapeá-la. Então use a função certa:

```
def regras(x):
    if x < 100:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x
    else:
        return (x + x)
     
lista = [100, 200, 1000, 3000, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(list(filter(regras,lista)))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3Q57yH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rrektlqr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/FilterList.py).

O código ainda faz pouco sentido porque parte dele faz o que um é para um `map()`, mas funciona como esperado.

Documentação do [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter).

Comment: Na verdade, é um filter e um map misturados, pois para valores maiores ou iguais a 100 o valor deve ser duplicado, então apenas `filter` não resolverá o problema. Precisará de ambos `filter` e `map`.

Answer (score 2):

Como o Maniero comentou, a lógica da sua função é um pouco obscura, pois parte dela funciona como um filtro, outra como um mapa. São coisas conceitualmente distintas, que fazem coisas distintas.

Quando você utiliza o `map`, será gerado uma nova sequência com o retorno da função indicada para cada item da sequência original. Se a função não retornar valor, será inferido `None`, por isso surgem tais valores na sua sequência final.

Já com o `filter` será gerado uma nova sequência com os valores da sequência original para quais a função indicada retornar um valor verdadeiro que, quando se tratando de números, será qualquer número diferente de 0. Assim, se você aplicar um filtro e retornar `x + x`, a sequência final terá o valor original `x`, pois se `x` não é zero, o valor `x + x` será, também, diferente de zero e, portanto, verdadeiro. A função `filter` não altera os valores originais, apenas filtra.

Sendo assim, o que você precisa fazer é separar as lógicas: primeiro, filtre sua sequência com os valores desejados e depois aplique o mapa para modificá-los. Se a intenção é remover os ímpares menores que 100, então:

```
filtrado = filter(lambda x: x >= 100 or x % 2 == 0, numeros)
```

Ou seja, `filtrado` será uma sequência com os valores de `numeros` que são maiores ou iguais a 100 ou pares. Agora, basta aplicar o mapa que dobra os valores maiores ou iguais a 100:

```
resultado = map(lambda x: x + x if x >= 100 else x, filtrado)
```

Porém, o que `map` retorna (assim como `filter`) são geradores, não listas. Caso queira como listas, precisa fazer a conversão:

```
resultado = list(map(lambda x: x + x if x >= 100 else x, filtrado))
```

Assim, o código seria:

```
>>> numeros = [100, 200, 1000, 3000, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> filtrado = filter(lambda x: x >= 100 or x % 2 == 0, numeros)
>>> resultado = list(map(lambda x: x + x if x >= 100 else x, filtrado))
>>> print(resultado)
[200, 400, 2000, 6000, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tem necessidade de você usar dois `if`, você pode usar o `else` no lugar:

```
def regras(x):
    if x < 100:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x
    else:
        return (x+x)


v1 = list(map(regras,lista))
print(v1)
```

Se você quer ignorar os `None`, basta usar o `filter` para fazer isso:

```
 arr  = [1, 2, 3, None, None, 4, 5]
 arr = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, arr))
```

A função do `filter` é criar um novo objeto contendo apenas os valores que são avaliados como `True` pela expressão `lambda x: x is not None`, onde `x` representa cada valor da sua `list`.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/qXaq9I)

Eu sugeriria que você refatore o seu código para ficar mais legível e menor:

```
def regras(x):
    if x >= 100:
        return x+x    
    return x if x % 2 == 0 else None
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema https://ideone.com/QieZFP

Comment: Viu a edição? ....

Comment: Sim, vi, e continua errado.

Comment: Agora sim, depois que eu fiz você arrumou :P Mas não dentro do exemplo dele. mas ainda ficou ruim porque executa ambos.